# Потокобезопасные Контейнеры

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Всем Привет

Я тут читаю «Параллельное программирование в действии» и там автор указывает что встроенный, например стэк не подходит для многопоточных программ из-за Гонки Данных. Поэтому он создал для него обертку, которая обеспечивает безопасность данных.

Получается если я хочу юзать тот или иной контейнер мне нужно его переделать под Thread Safe?

Comment: если хочется использовать любую структуру в многопоточном коде, нужно обеспечить её поточную безопасность. Иногда достаточно мютекса, иногда аккуратного разделения кода

Comment: Виноват **не** встроенный стек, а плохой алгоритм, использующий общие данные для разных потоков. Писать прогу надо правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, чаще всего стандартные реализации не рассчитаны на использование в параллельной среде.

Многопоточность приносит очень много проблем с потокобезопасностью. Критические секции, мьютексы и прочие механизмы синхронизации сказываются на времени выполнении программ, так как появляется дополнительный код, который также расходует процессорное время.

Стоит ли писать данный код самому? - для самообразования стоит, в иных случаях лучше воспользоваться готовыми вариантами. Имеется огромное количество библиотек с такими структурами и алгоритмами.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ! А какие библиотеки использовать? Boost?

Comment: @ErcodY boost хорош да, другие ищите если не хватает его функционала.

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего многопоточные контейнеры вообще не используются. Вместо них используются обычные, с ними либо работают только в одном потоке, либо используют внешнюю по отношению к контейнеру синхронизацию.

Контейнеры со встроенным мьютексом бывают, но не применяются широко, т.к. они неэффективны и ограниченны.

Использование внешней по отношению к контейнеру блокировки даёт то преимущество, что можно поместить несколько операций под одну блокировку. Это и обеспечивает корректность многих сценариев, и более эффективно. Например:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), pred), v.end());
```

поддержку такого использования не получится обеспечить внутренним мьютексом, т.к. контейнер может меняться между вызовами его методов. И если бы можно было, то захват мьютекса был бы на каждую операцию, что дорого.

Бывают контейнеры, которые не требуют блокировки, и не используют внутренних мьютексов (lock-free). Их использовать больше смысла, но они не получаются из обычных путём доработки, они заранее разрабатываются с учётом многопоточности. В Boost есть [Boost.Lockfree](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/lockfree.html), например.